# ClojureScript Repl Security

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

We have two machines:

- server
- client

Server is running Clojure + Ring + ... standard ClojureScript webstack.

Client = some machine running Chorme/Firefox/Safari

Now, suppose Server is running a ClojureScriptRepl connection at port 9000 that Client can connect to to setup the ClojureScriptOne Repl.

This allows the server to control the client behavior in certain ways.

However, does this also allow the client to control the server? I.e. does the very act of running a ClojureScript repl allow the client to compromise/control/execute arbitrary code on the server (as running a Clojure Repl would).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Only strings are moving to server, and server just prints then as string. Practicly there's no overflow attack possibilities, and succeeding with java virtualmachine is not likely, and if it were possible a ton of software woult be wunerable.